# Error: Junk character at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x7F

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5, assembly

I am a newbie to Android NDK, I am using android-ndk-r5 to build the Gearoid source code. After several warning of the following type

```
warning: null characters ignored
```

the assembler terminates with the following error message:

```
Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0x7F
make: **** [/cygdrive/c/emus/Gearoid/obj/local/armabi/libgg.so] Error 1
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more error output? Where did the assembler/compiler report "null characters ignored"? What did the *.s files show in that location? Where did the final error occur? Unless it's been obsoleted, it's been awhile, I just saw.

Comment: At a guess, you aren't compiling a C source file.  What is your compiler command line exactly?

Comment: do not use cygwin to deal with android code. this is unpredictable. build on Linux machine

Comment: 7F is the max signed number for al, add one to al=7F and you trigger the overflow flag